# How to consume a legacy SOAP Web Service from Visual Studio 2022 .NET 6

Tags: soap, service, reference, asmx

When attempting to a Service Reference to a legacy 2.0 Web Reference ASMX in Visual Studio 2022 with a .NET 6 Framework project I go through the following steps:

-"Add Service Reference" wizard
-WCF Web Reference
-Specify URI to .asmx and namespace
-Next,Next, Finish

But the service that is added isn't providing the strongly typed entities in that the asmx contains in the wsdl.

If I add the service reference from a .NET 4.7.2 project through the Compatibility Option of Add Service Reference wizard then the strongly typed entities are included.

Is there a way to get all the strongly typed functionality in the newer frameworks?